# aplication in node.js says its registering but mongo isnt creating a new db

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

ok so mongo should create a new db and collection the first time the application register something but it isnt, even when it show data is posted correctly: POST /api/registrar_tarea 200 15.297 ms - 144

conection with mongo (xxxx where my pass and name go)

```
let db = mongoose.connection,
    dburl = 'mongodb://xxxx:xxxx@proyecto-shard-00-00-qyxqa.mongodb.net:27017,proyecto-shard-00-01-qyxqa.mongodb.net:27017,proyecto-shard-00-02-qyxqa.mongodb.net:27017/tareas?ssl=true&replicaSet=proyecto-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true',

    port = 4000;
```

model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let shema_tareas = new mongoose.Schema(
   {
      nombre: { type: String, required: true }, 
      fecha: { type: Date, required: true },
      prioridad: { type: String, required: true },
      encargado: { type: String, required: true },    
      descripcion: { type: String, required: true },
      estado: { type: String, require: true }

   } 
);
module.exports= mongoose.model('tarea', shema_tareas);
```

api:

```
const modelo_tareas = require('./tareas.model')

module.exports.registrar = (req, res) => {
    let nuevo_tarea = new modelo_tareas(
        {
      nombre: req.body.nombre, 
      fecha: req.body.fecha,
      prioridad: req.body.prioridad,
      encargado: req.body.encargado,  
      descripcion: req.body.descripcion,
      estado: 'Activo'  
        }
    );
    nuevo_tarea.save(function (error) {

        if (error) {
            res.json(
                {
                    success: false,
                    msg: `No se pudo registrar el tarea, ocurrió el siguiente error ${error}`
                }
            );
        } else {


            res.json(
                {

                    success: true,
                    msg: `Se registro correctamente el tarea.`

                }
            )
        }

    });

};
```

sorry for so much code but im desperate

Answer (score 0):

ok so im not entirely sure what happened but it fixed itself when i made a test using postman